# How does Bash reads its input?

Tags: bash, shell

When reading Bash Reference Manual in [shell operation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Operation), it says:

> 1. Reads its input from a file (see Shell Scripts), from a string supplied as an argument to the -c invocation option (see Invoking Bash), or from the user’s terminal.

Here are my questions:

1. what is the difference of the 3 ways of reading input?
2. can a script have arguments? like `$ ./script arg1 arg2 ...`

And when I type some command one the terminal like:

```
$ command1 arg1 arg2 ...
```

How does Bash know `command1` is a executable (no further processing, just execute it) not a script (to read the content of the script)?

Comment: Where's Tim when you need him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The main difference is that when reading from the terminal, the shell displays prompts. Otherwise, there's no difference

   ```
   $ echo ls > script
   $ bash script
   script
   $ bash -c ls
   script
   $ ls
   script
   ```

   The shell knows whether it's running interactively, and some commands might behave differently based on that, too.
2. Yes, it's a common thing. arguments to a string fill its positional parameters. Search for `$@` and `$1`, `$2` etc. in `man bash`.

   See ARGUMENTS, FUNCTIONS, and ALIASES in `man bash`. In brief, when you run `command1 arg1 arg2`, bash first tries to expand the alias `command1` and run the result, or to run a function `command1`, and if even that isn't possible, it tries to find the command in its `$PATH`.